# How to call a code-behind method from aspx page?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

I've an object that contains a field called **DevList** which is defined like this

```
public List<string> DevList { get; set; }
```

I also defined a method called **DisplayListOfDevelopers** that is supposed to concatenate the list of developers and display it as a one string.

This is how I'm calling the method from aspx.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Developer(s)">
 <ItemTemplate>
   <asp:Label 
        ID="_lblDevList" 
        runat="server" 
        Text= '<%# DisplayListOfDevelopers(DevList) %>'>
   </asp:Label>
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

But, I'm getting this error: **The name 'DevList' does not exist in the current context**

Am I missing something?

## EDIT

```
_gvStatus = ds;
_gvStatus.DataBind();
```

Where ds is just a list of objects that contains the **DevList** for now.

Thanks for helping

Comment: where did you define the variable in your codebehind ?

Comment: Does the DevList property seats within a class which connected to the gridview/listview datasource?

Comment: Do you want to display the full list *for each row*?

Comment: Yes, I want, for instance, add a <br/> at the end of each name so that developers affected to a project are displayed fron top to bottom not one next to the other. And that's what the function DisplayListOfDevelopers is supposed to accomplish.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Assuming this is how your class looks:

```
public class MyItem
{
    public List<string> DevList { get; set; }
}
```

And that

```
ds = List<MyItem>();
```

Do this:

In your code-behind:

```
protected string DisplayListOfDevelopers(object _devList)
{
    //Cast your dev list into the correct object
}
```

In your markup:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Developer(s)">
 <ItemTemplate>
   <asp:Label 
        ID="_lblDevList" 
        runat="server" 
        Text='<%# DisplayListOfDevelopers(Eval("DevList")) %>'>
   </asp:Label>
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Just be sure to make the function in your code-behind is protected or public.

Comment: Thanks. It's working now. However, I heard Eval is bad for performance.

Comment: As opposed to what? And/or do you have a reference?