# How to pass list as parameter to a method in .aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I must bind a gridview to a method which returns `list<>`, there are few multi select lookups in the list, for this I have a method which returns `dictionary<int, string>`.

In the list I have the multi select item values as `{1, xyz}, {2, abc}`

So I must display in the grid as xyz, abc.

For this I have written a method `FormatString` which is called in gridview binding.. i.e aspx page

`<%# FormatString(?????????) %>`

I must pass `list<>` in the ???? to retreive the data..

Please suggest me some solutions..

Comment: Please Check this link

Source : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12754016/how-to-call-a-code-behind-method-from-aspx-page

Comment: Please check this link 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12754016/how-to-call-a-code-behind-method-from-aspx-page

Answer (score 1):

```
'<%# FormatString(Container.DataItem as YourListType) %>'

public String FormatString(YourListType listObj )
{
   //do what  you want.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way

Get the values to a different list from your dictionary items

```
var items = yourDictionary.Values.SelectMany(x => x).ToList();
```

Then you can simply bind the list to `gridview`