# Is it possible to pass a format string to Bind() from code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

- Webforms, .NET 4.51

Using standard databinding as follows:

```
<asp:TextBox TabIndex="254" Text='<%# Bind("ClientTwoDateOfBirth", "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}") %>'  ID="txtClientTwoDob" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Is it possible to call the code behind to get the formatting string dynamically? Something like the following (which does not work):

```
<asp:TextBox TabIndex="254" Text='<%# Bind("ClientTwoDateOfBirth", "{" + GetFormatStringFromCodeBehind() + "}") %>'  ID="txtClientTwoDob" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can u provide me the code behid function code.. I cant understand exactly  what is exactly

Comment: Below link will help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12754016/how-to-call-a-code-behind-method-from-aspx-page

Comment: @Balaji That example is only for one way binding via Eval(). I want to maintain two way data binding using Bind() but determine the format string (second parameter dynamically)

Answer (score 0):

you can get required FormatString for textbox from code behind by

aspx

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# GetFormatStringFromCodeBehind(    Eval("columnName")) %>'></asp:TextBox>
```

aspx.cs

```
      public string GetFormatStringFromCodeBehind(object obj)
    {
        return Convert.ToDateTime(obj).ToString("dd/MM/yyy");
    }
```

you should use Eval instead of Bind

Comment: I still want to maintain two way data binding via Bind()

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to have something more complex than a plain string inside `Bind()` expression. There was even a bug report about this (almost identical to your question) - [Data Binding with "Bind" and Formatting Problem (ASP.Net)](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/338632/data-binding-with-bind-and-formatting-problem-asp-net) and official response:

> Posted by Microsoft on 1/22/2009 at 7:23 AM
>
> The behavior you are seeing is by design. The Bind expression is a
>   very specialized part of ASP.NET code generation and it has a
>   limitation that the format parameter must be a literal, you sample
>   fails because the format string is instead a function. You can read
>   more about the details of Bind here:
>   http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2007/06/29/how-asp-net-databinding-deals-with-eval-and-bind-statements.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

What I normally do is to Use DataBinder.Eval to fetch the value of the TextBox at PreRender and set it. You can add a condition that checks if you are in edit mode.

See sample code below:

In your .aspx:

```
<asp:TextBox OnPreRender="txtClientTwoDob_PreRender" TabIndex="254" Text='<%# Bind("ClientTwoDateOfBirth") %>'  ID="txtClientTwoDob" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

and in your code behind:

```
    protected void txtClientTwoDob_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox txtClientTwoDob = (TextBox)sender;
        //You can check also if you are in edit mode or not before performing this
        txtClientTwoDob.Text = DataBinder.Eval(txtClientTwoDob, "Text", "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}");
    }
```

I hope this helps.